# codeigniter left join without wrapping character

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, between

I'm having trouble generating a query in Codeigniter. The problem is

```
$this->db->select('user.*')
    ->join('user_group', 'user.group_id BETWEEN user_group.start_range AND user_group.end_range', 'left');
```

This code generates the following query:

```
SELECT `user`.* FROM (`user`) LEFT JOIN `user_group` ON `user`.`group_id` `BETWEEN` user_group.start_range AND user_group.end_range
```

Here, the mysql can not recognize the **`BETWEEN`** which is inside the quote character, how can I generate the query without wrapping with the quote character. Please, give me any suggestion.

I'm using codeigniter 2.2.0

Comment: you need to use >= and <= operator to perform join as codeigniter won't work with sql between operator so change your query to $this->db->select('user.*')
    ->join('user_group', 'user.group_id >= user_group.start_range AND user.group_id <= user_group.end_range', 'left');

Comment: Well CI 2.2.x doesn't have the escape flag as the 4th parameter ( to escape the values and identifiers ) on the join, whereas in CI 3.0, it does. So you'll need to go with what imran qasim suggested if you are using CI 2.2.0!

Comment: Thanks for your help, the solution imran qasim gave works fine

Answer (score 0):

You would need to either override the `$_reserved_identifiers` variable in the `CI_DB_driver` class to look like the following

```
var $_reserved_identifiers  = array('*', 'BETWEEN'); // Identifiers that should NOT be escaped
```

(Note im not sure what if this reduces security)

https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/2.2-stable/system/database/DB_driver.php#L67

The other option is to replicate the between operator using `>=` and `<=`